# ASP.NET SQL SessionState or Custom solution?

Tags: asp.net, session-state

The ASP.NET SQL SessionState provider seems excessive for my requirements. SQL Server has to be 'configured' to support it and I have questions about how optimized it is (i.e. is there one db hit to fetch the whole session or one for every session item requested?).

I think I could implement a custom solution very easily that I would understand and easily redeploy to other projects. Is there something fundamental I haven't considered here and an obvious reason why the built in SessionState handler is the 'best' way to go?

Just to clarify, our applications run on single servers at the moment. My main motivation for doing this is to enable Session to persist across IIS restarts and therefore provide more reliability for users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could use **StateServer** mode.

StateServer mode stores session state in a process, referred to as the ASP.NET state service, that is separate from the ASP.NET worker process or IIS application pool.

Using this mode ensures that session state is preserved if the Web application is restarted and also makes session state available to multiple Web servers in a Web farm.

more info at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx

Comment: Sorry you must have missed my edit - I need to preserve the session across application restarts which InProc doesn't support

Answer (score 1):

It takes just minutes to setup SQL session state server (assuming you have SQL server already running). I can't imagine that you can write anything in less time than it would take to at least try out what already exists and is free and supported by MS.

A proven, built-in/off-the-shelf solution is always better place to start than custom. You may still end up with a custom solution, but don't pick it because you didn't bother to test what is already available to you.